# play 2.1.1 framework does not recompile (refresh)

Tags: playframework, recompile

I am new to play framework. I have downloaded the latest version (2.1.1) I am trying to follow the steps from the video tutorial http://www.playframework.com/ but when I make any changes to the code, save it and then refresh localhost:9000 - it still shows the old page. I also tried: "play clean", "play compile" and still no result. Any suggestions?
I am using javac 1.7.0._21 and making the changes through eclipse.

Comment: Have you see on the Play SBT Console message like this : `Compiling xx Scala sources to yourprojectpath\target\scala-2.10\classes...` When you use `play run` command you should see the changes of your page.

Comment: Hava you solved that problem? I'm having the same problem too.

Answer (score 2):

Try using **~ run**, instead i.e

```
[My first application] $ ~ run
```

This should recompile the code every time you make a change. The following page contains more information: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/PlayConsole

Answer (score 0):

I use intelij as my editor, and before doing editing and refreshing, I start up the app with this command :

```
play debug run
```

You should see something like this starting up...

```
....
[info] Done updating.
--- (Running the application from SBT, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ***build.sbt***, change this line:

```
fork in run := true
```

to

```
fork in run := false
```